# Modify from one plugin the Bootstrap data from another

Tags: grails

I have several plugins in my grails project. One of them, let's call it plugin-A, inserts some data into de DB. I want to change this data, or better to prevent this data to be loaded from a new plugin (plugin-B)

Of course, that I could change the plugin-A to insert an `if` in the Bootstrap but this is not it's responsibility, so what I want is a method to change the PluginABootstrap data from PluginBBootstrap.

Comment: What's the issue you are facing in doing so?

Comment: The plugin-A inserts some default questions in the DB, and that's correct. But know I want to do the evolution of that plugin, but without modifying it. This evolution is in plugin-B, and is have to change the questions and insert some more.

Comment: So where is the issue here? Just bootstrap the data there.

Comment: The only way which could work is to create PluginABootstrap in B plugin with exactly the same name of class and the same package. In this case, class should be overriden by second plugin and that implementation used. To set order of plugins use `loadBefore` or `loadAfter` in plugin definition class

Comment: I get this error: 
`Invalid duplicate class definition of class PluginABootStrap`